# WARNING: can't open config file: ./bin/openssl.cnf

Tags: windows, openssl, xampp, ssl-certificate

> makecert

and press enter then this error occurs.

I tried with solutions provided but that not worked for me.

ex: **set OPENSSL_CONF=c:/OpenSSL_Win64/bin/openssl.cnf**

```html
<pre>WARNING: can't open config file: ./bin/openssl.cnf
Unable to load config info from ./bin/openssl.cnf
WARNING: can't open config file: ./bin/openssl.cnf
Error opening Private Key privkey.pem
5344:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\
bss_file.c:398:fopen('privkey.pem','rb')
5344:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:40
0:
unable to load Private Key
WARNING: can't open config file: ./bin/openssl.cnf
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
server.csr: No such file or directory
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\.rnd
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\privkey.pem
Could Not Find C:\xampp\apache\server.csr
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.

-----
Das Zertifikat wurde erstellt.
The certificate was provided.</pre>
```

Comment: You forget to add an system environment variable correctly for OpenSSL on Windows! You maybe set it to the wrong path or you forgot to run CMD as a Admin!

Answer (score 8):

#### Explaining your problem

This error occurs mainly on Windows computers when you are using OpenSSL package or [the Windows installer](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)!

> The reason is that *[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)* failed to locate the ***openssl.cnf* file**!

---

#### Step-by-Step instructions

I will recommend that you do the following (windows only):

1. Open your command prompt **as Administrator** (few OpenSSL commands opens in random state), thus when OpenSSL tries to write stuff on your disk it fails.

   - *Try this easy and fast method:* Open the Run dialog box with [image: Win+R key], type `cmd` and hit [image: Enter]
2. Now before you run any OpenSSL command type the following:

   `set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\[PATH TO YOUR OPENSSL DIRECTORY]\bin\openssl.cfg`

   - A sample path is: `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg`. For Windows (x64-bit) use `C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg`!

After you did this now you are good to go with your OpenSSL stuff. Try `openssl version` and the error is gone.

> Remember that everytime you open a command prompt you have to run the above command unless you set this as your environment variable.

---

#### Solve your problem

Your problem could be:

- You set the environment variable into the folder *`OpenSSL_Win64`*. It should be maybe in **`OpenSSL-Win64`**!
- You forgot maybe to run the command prompt **as a Administrator**!
- You set the environment variable to the file `openssl.cnf` but it must be **`openssl.cfg`**!

---

#### Helpful sites

Read also:

- [WARNING: can’t open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf on Windows 7](http://blog.webspheretools.com/2011/11/17/warning-cant-open-config-file-usrlocalsslopenssl-cnf/) (another detailed instructions for your problem)
- [How To Add/Edit Environment Variables in Windows 7](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/) (helpful if you want set the environment variables forever on your Windows!)

Comment: Thanks for this! I installed the 64-bit version but had copied the SET command from someone who installed the 32-bit, so it was the wrong file path.

Answer (score 4):

Manually creating an *openssl.cnf* file in the correct location can solve the problem.

[Here](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates#SSLCert-4) is a file template (edit as needed):

```
#
# OpenSSL configuration file.
#

# Establish working directory.

dir                 = .

[ ca ]
default_ca              = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
serial                  = $dir/serial
database                = $dir/certindex.txt
new_certs_dir               = $dir/certs
certificate             = $dir/cacert.pem
private_key             = $dir/private/cakey.pem
default_days                = 365
default_md              = md5
preserve                = no
email_in_dn             = no
nameopt                 = default_ca
certopt                 = default_ca
policy                  = policy_match

[ policy_match ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName         = match
organizationName            = match
organizationalUnitName          = optional
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress                = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                = 1024          # Size of keys
default_keyfile             = key.pem       # name of generated keys
default_md              = md5               # message digest algorithm
string_mask             = nombstr       # permitted characters
distinguished_name          = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions              = v3_req

[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name             Prompt string
#-------------------------    ----------------------------------
0.organizationName          = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_max            = 40
localityName                = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName             = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min             = 2
countryName_max             = 2
commonName              = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max              = 64

# Default values for the above, for consistency and less typing.
# Variable name             Value
#------------------------     ------------------------------
0.organizationName_default      = My Company
localityName_default            = My Town
stateOrProvinceName_default     = State or Providence
countryName_default         = US

[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints            = CA:TRUE
subjectKeyIdentifier            = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier          = keyid:always,issuer:always

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints            = CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier            = hash
```

Answer (score 0):

When install the application penSSL_Win64, will be located in C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64 so , you need to set to this path with a console command and write:
**set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg**

Comment: doesnt seem to be working (updated into right path)